# How does attack interact with defence items?

Tags: league-of-legends

Let's say that I play Zed and bought Hydra and my enemy is Shen and bought Omen. How much damage will I do to him if my only item is Hydra and his only item is Omen? 75+AD - 70+Def?
This is how LoL works or it's more complicated than that?

Comment: Does attack works the same way as defence in the post you show me?

Comment: Yes the linked answer shows you the formula. Quick example:

You have 100 AD total and you attack an enemy with 100 Armor

The damage reduction is calculated with 100 / (100 + 100) which is 50 % (result is always in percent).

So you will effectively deal 50 damage.